# Output of callback function not getting logged (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to wrap my head around asynchronous JS using callbacks. In my html, i have a button and a div area to display text.

```
<button class="btn btn-default">Fetch User</button>
<hr>
<div></div>
```

My JS is as follows:

```
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const div = document.querySelector("div");

const setText = (text) => {
  div.textContent = text
}


const checkAuth = ca => {
  setText('Checking Auth...')
  setTimeout(() => {
    ca(true);
  }, 2000);
};

const fetchUser = fu => {
  setText('Fetching User...')
  setTimeout(() => {
    fu ({ name: "PENNYWISE" }) ;
  }, 2000);
};

const evilLaughter = el => {
  setText('Red balloon drifting your way...')
  setTimeout(() => {
    el ({ laughter: "HA HA HA" }) ;
  }, 2000);
};

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  checkAuth(isauth => {
    if (isauth) {
      fetchUser(user => {
        setText(user.name);
          evilLaughter( intro => {
              setText(intro.laughter)
          });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I expect the code to output in the foll sequence:
Checking Auth --> Fetching User --> PENNYWISE --> Red balloon drifting your way --> HA HA HA

However, the code is not outputting in the desired sequence. It is outputting as follows:
Checking Auth --> Fetching User --> Red balloon drifting your way --> HA HA HA

So i am trying to figure why is 'PENNYWISE' not showing. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: it should be  giving output as expected, try `const setText = (text) => {
  div.textContent += text
}`. this will concat all output to your div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>     setText(user.name);
>       evilLaughter( intro => {
>           setText(intro.laughter)
>       });
> ```

The code which leads to `setText("PENNYWISE")` is **immediately** followed by the code which leads to `setText("Red balloon drifting your way")`.

There is no delay between the statements.

The DOM gets updated, then it is immediately updated again.

This is too fast for there to be a repaint of the display, and even if it wasn't, it would be too fast for the human eye to see.

Comment: got it... yup. 'PENNYWISE' is getting logged, but was not showing. did a workaround by adding a timeout... `setTimeout(()=>setText('Red balloon drifting your way...'), 2000);`